# name look up for a class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the below code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
template<typename T>
struct A{
    using type = typename T::type;
};
// #1
struct B{
    using type = int;
    A<B>::type value;
};
int main() {

}
```

I use some rules I found in the standard to validate the code whether it's legal,Firstly, point of instantiation, Because `class B` is not a template and `A` is a class template, So the following rule would be applied, that is:

[[temp.point#4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#4)

> Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately **precedes the namespace scope declaration or definition** that refers to the specialization.

It means the point of instantiation for `A<B>` is prior to the definition of `class B`, it probably at `#1` in my code. As far as here, I encounter a question, that is, At the point of `#1`, the name of `B` can't be found. I hold the question and continue to under go the remainder of [temp.point] section(Sometimes, the remainder of a section would resolve some confusions). I find a quote that probably relate to this question, it's:

[[temp.point#7]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#7)

> The instantiation context of an **expression** that depends on the template arguments is the set of declarations with external linkage declared prior to the point of instantiation of the template specialization in the same translation unit.

Here , `typename T::type` seems to be a qualified-id, but not an id-expression. So it doesn't satisfy the pre-condition. However `typename T::type` is a dependent type. Dependent name resolution is that:

[[temp.dep.res#1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.res#1)

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> > 1. Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> > 2. Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point]) and from the definition context.

Here, the second rule does not be considered, Because it's not a function call. If I do not misunderstand the first rule, it means the name `B` must be declared before the point of definition of `class template A`, So, I wonder how name `B` can be found at the point of instantiation for `A<B>`? even `B::type`.  As far as now, I have not found any quote can interpret this. If I miss something or misunderstand the standard, Please correct me.

In addition, Three compilers all agree the code is [legal](https://godbolt.org/z/ETPqyY).

Comment: The problem here is that `typename T::type` is not an id-expression. Following the grammar production bring us to simple expansion of [typename-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier). It's not at all under the expression tree.

Comment: in `A<B>`, indeed `B` is incomplete, but `B`'s parts prior to `A<B>::type` would be known.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh, yes, it's qualified-id but not an id-expression.

Comment: @Jarod42 But, it require it used in the definition of `class B`,  The key point is that the instantiation for `A<B>` is outside of the definition of `class B` and prior to that.

Comment: Looks like http://wg21.link/cwg287 to me

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks, However where's quote say "it is also visible to any template that uses A through a template parameter.", Could you help answer this question?

Comment: @jackX I'm not good at templates to answer the question, sorry

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I still thank you for your comment, It's very helpful to me. This is a defect in the standard.

Comment: _Dependent name resolution is that_ `type` in `using type = typename T::type;` is not a dependent name, it is a member of an unknown specialization.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer we back to  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462543/is-it-a-defect-int-the-standard-about-dependent-name-resolution-for-template?noredirect=1#comment110474444_62462543) to talk about these issues.