# Is it a defect in the standard about dependent name resolution for template

Tags: templates, c++17, language-lawyer

About how lookup the dependent name for template, The standard only gives a little sentence like this, there's no more:

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> > 1. Declarations that are visible at the **point of definition of the template**.
> > 2. Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point]) and from the definition context.

Consider the below code

```cpp
struct Test{
  using type = int;
};
// #1
template<typename T>
struct TMP{
  using type = typename T::type;
};
int main(){
  TMP<Test>::type v = 0;
}
```

For this code, the name `type` indeed a dependent name because T is a template parameter and here is not a function call, So, the only relevant bullet point is Number 1. It only says the dependent name shall be visible before the **template definition**, It means in my code, the declaration shall be visible at `#1`. In actually, `typename T::type` is a qualified-id, hence qualified name lookup rules apply to it and because `T` is a template parameter, So the lookup action shall be occurred after given a template argument, namely, during the instantiation of a specialization for such a template. But the quote I cited does not say anything about this. So, I wonder Is it a defect in the standard? If I miss anything that interpret this in the standard, please cite them for this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216356/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-is-it-a-defect-in-the-standard-about-dependent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9585016/language-lawyer) comments, in §"Unknown specializations" of [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)

> Within a template definition, certain names are deduced to belong to 
>     an unknown specialization, in particular,
>
> - a qualified name, if any name that appears to the left of :: is a dependent type that is not a member of the current instantiation
> - ...

In your `struct TMP`,

- the type `T` is indeed a *dependent type*
- the expression `typename T::type` is a qualified name and the left if `::` is a dependent type
- that expression becomes an *unknown specialization*

Then it is said:

> Members of unknown specialization are always dependent, and are looked up and bound at the point of instantiation as all dependent names

which allows the lookup of `TMP<Test>::type` at the point of *instanciation*.

Comment: _The type `T` is indeed a dependent name_ [No it isn't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#def:name,dependent)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer ah, a dependent type then? `The following types are dependent types: * template parameter` same page

Comment: Looks like a dependent type.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer sorry about the wording mistake... let me correct this

Comment: cppreference doesn't reflect the current state of the standard wording, more like the future of it

Comment: @LanguageLawyer agreed but even there the wording is very difficult to get right, and it is even more so on the standard. I spend some time in trying to understand your comments and project those on what is being said on cppref, unfortunately the references you posted to the standard were not very helpful, although certainly more accurate.

Comment: @Raffi  Your answers is a standard answers except `the expression typename T::type `, it's not a expression due to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#3).

Comment: @Raffi In addition, Could you please cite quotes in the standard in your answers, I think that will be more persuasive